# Filling String list with a recursive method ( Recursive fill method )

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, methods

I want to write a recursive method that **fills and returns a `String[]` list** of random balls for either "blue" or "red" of length `n` where `n` is a random odd number.

I wrote this method to generate an odd number in range 1-10 to use as a parameter for the recursive method.

```
public int ranNum (int ranN) {
    int min = 1
    int max = 10
    
    Random r = new Random();
    
    ranN = min + r.nextInt((max - min)/2)*2;

    return ranN;
}
```

Is the (random odd number) method right? How to implement the recursive method?

Comment: you have to call the function in your function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recursive function is a function which calls itself directly or via any amount of intermediate function calls.

The first step usually is to think about the termination. In your case you want to either count from `1` up to `n` or from `n` down to `1`. And when the function terminates you have the choice of either returning the final value (it's called tail-recursion) or start building up your answer by traversing the call stack upwards. The later is being used, when you have one long calculation and you just want the last value (e.g. Fibonacci-Numbers).

And then do the work in every step:

```java
String[] tailRecursion(int n, String[] accumulator, Random rnd)
{
    if(n == 0) {
        return accumulator;
    }
    accumulator[n-1] = rnd.nextBoolean() ? "red" : "blue";
    return tailRecursion(n-1, accumulator, rnd);
}
```

The method is called via `tailRecursion(10, new String[10], new Random())`

Comment: the method that I wrote to generate an odd number (n) is it right?

Comment: It seems to be correct. But you wanted to have just two outcomes, "blue" and "red", here a random Boolean is sufficient.